# Is there a Pandora client for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: apps, 7.x

Loved the Pandora client application on my Android and iPhone devices. Didn't see one on Windows Phone 7. Is it called something different by chance?

Comment: Ita coming.  Like most apps.

Comment: Related meta question about whether this question belongs on the site: http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/4/26

Comment: Welcome to the Windows Phone site. We generally require [some effort](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking your question such that we can solve [an actual problem](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) rather than re-iterating Marketplace or Google search results. [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) talks about this type of question in more detail, you could alternatively ask in which ways WP7 applications can be searched, answers would be on WP7, on MS site, and so on...

Comment: **Related:** [Chat discussion between us](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3224/discussion-between-jim-mckeeth-and-tom-wijsman)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no Pandora app for WIndows phones, but the following equivalents exist:

1. [MetroRadio](http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/Internet-Utilities/Radio-TV-Player/MetroRadio-131106.shtml)
2. [Radio Controlled](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/8e43d66c-dace-40e3-98cb-bc6b5bdd7b8f)
3. [WpFandora](http://download.pandaapp.com/windows-phone-app/wpfandora-2.2.0.0-id1967.html)

WpFandora is an [unofficial app](http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-app-review-wpfandora) that I guess can be used till the official Pandora comes out (if it ever does)

Comment: Keep in mind that Pandora loves breaking their api, but the developers of these apps react quickly to the changes and submit updates. Be prepared for the inability to login every several months, but since Pandora doesnt support wp7 yet there is no official app. prrao's list above is the way to go.